# Hiding ModelMultipleChoiceField on template for custom input

Tags: django, django-forms

I want the user to select a number of elements belonging to a certain model. I don't want to use the default 'ctrl+click' input of django forms, but create a table of checkboxes myself.

For that reason I hide the ModelMultipleChoiceField by defining the widget:

```
field = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(..., widget=forms.MultipleHiddenInput())
```

Then I add the form element into the template as follows:

```
<form method="POST" class="locklist-form" id="locklist-form">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.field }}
</form>
```

At this step, I expect the select-option elements to be added to HTML page (as hidden), so that I can reach to element options and modify them with javascript. However, it doesn't add anything to the HTML page.

I use this approach with other type of form fieds. For a `TextField` HTML page have a hidden element as shown:
[image: Hidden element of form.TextField]

Why doesn't it work with `ModelMultipleChoiceField`? How can I modify the choices of this field with Javascript?

Edit: 
[MultipleHiddenInput renders only if with initial data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTxEX.png) is a similar question. But applying it doesn't lead to the expected solution. In this question, it is expected to render the following as hidden:
[image: expected render]
But following the [MultipleHiddenInput renders only if with initial data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTxEX.png), when I modify the form constructor as:

```
form = MyForm(initial={'field':MyModel.objects.all()})
```

Rendered element is as follows:
[image: render got]

It maybe useful, but not exactly the expected one. I need to mark a few options as selected, among a list of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it using Javascript, instead of depending on Django's capabilities. I add the form with ModelMultipleChoiceField directly to the template (not hidden). Then I run a Javascript script, when the page is loaded:

```
var field = document.getElementById('id_field');
selecter.setAttribute('class', 'hidden');
```

CSS definition of hidden class is as follows:

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

This gets me to the desired situation. ModelMultipleChoiceField is rendered hidden as follows:
[image: satisfied case]

At this point, I can modify certain items through Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('id_field').options[index].selected = boolValue;
```